# Converting categorical variables to numbers based on frequency in a single line

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

This is similar to [LabelEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) from scikit-learn, but with the requirement that the number value assignments occur in order of frequency of the category, i.e., the higher occurring category being assigned the highest/lowest (depending on use-case) number.

E.g. If the variable can take values `[a, b, c]` with frequencies such as

```
  Category 
0        a 
0        a 
0        a 
0        a 
0        a 
1        b 
1        b 
1        b 
1        b 
1        b 
1        b 
1        b 
1        b 
1        b 
1        b 
2        c 
2        c
```

`a` occurs 5 times, `b` occurs 10 times and `c` occurs 2 times. 
Then I want the replacements be done as `b=1`, `a=2` and `c=3`.

Comment: What do you want to happen if two values have the same frequency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Vivek Kumar, I used the map functionality, using a dict of the sorted column values as key and their position as value:

```
data.Category = data.Category.map(dict(zip(data.Category.value_counts().index, range(1, len(data.Category.value_counts().index)+1))))
```

Looks a bit dirty, would be much better to divide it into a couple of lines like this:

```
sorted_indices = data.Category.value_counts().index
data.Category = data.Category.map(dict(zip(sorted_indices, range(1, len(sorted_indices)+1))))
```

This is the closest I have to my requirement. The output looks like this:

```
    Category
0          2
1          2
2          2
3          2
4          2
5          1
6          1
7          1
8          1
9          1
10         1
11         1
12         1
13         1
14         1
15         3
16         3
```

Answer (score 2):

See [`argsort`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.argsort.html):

```
df['Order'] = df['Frequency'].argsort() + 1
df
```

returns

```
  Category  Frequency  Order
0        a          5      3
1        b         10      1
2        c          2      2
```

Comment: I'm sorry to mislead you, frequency column is not part of the data. I'll edit the representation.

Comment: @Alex, you should also note that your result does not match the desired result shown in the question.  The frequency 5 should be assigned to 2, not 3.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using pandas, you can use its [`map()` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame([['a'], ['b'], ['c']], columns=['category'])

print(data)

  category
0        a
1        b
2        c

mapping_dict = {'b':1, 'a':2, 'c':3}

print(data['category'].map(mapping_dict))

0    2
1    1
2    3
```

LabelEncoder uses [np.unique to find the unique values](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f0ab589f/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py#L112) present in a column which returns values in alphabetically sorted order, so you cannot use the custom ordering in it.

Comment: Hi Vivek, your solution assumes that I know the numerical labels beforehand. But I wouldn't know that unless I saw the frequency and manually wrote the `mapping_dict`. This is not what I'm after though.